# WordPress Theme Installation Error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

While I am installing wordpress theme, it's showing

> "**Installation Failed: The package could not be installed - The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet**"

I have installed with various methods, but same issue. (Eg: Cpanel, WP-Dashboard).

[image]

Comment: style.css not proper format

Answer (score 0):

There are many things when you got error like style.css missing

**One:**  first of all into your WordPress root directory open wp-content-themes->your theme name->header.php. The check the style.css properly call or not?

**Two:** If first step is ok then open your style.css and add your theme name into comment sections something like this:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Your Theme Name
Theme URI:      https://themeisle.com/themes/your-them-name/
Author:         ThemeIsle
Author URI:     https://themeisle.com
Description:    Hestia is a modern WordPress theme for professionals. It fits creative business, small businesses (restaurants, wedding planners, sport/medical shops), startups, corporate businesses, online agencies and firms, portfolios, ecommerce (WooCommerce), and freelancers. It has a multipurpose one-page design, widgetized footer, blog/news page and a clean look, is compatible with: Flat Parallax Slider, Photo Gallery, Travel Map and Elementor Page Builder . The theme is responsive, WPML, Retina ready, SEO friendly, and uses Material Kit for design.
*/
```

**Three:** rezip your theme and install it again see then its working fine or not ? for more [check here](https://www.wpproblems.com/missing-the-style-css-stylesheet-error/)

Thanks